# Columns not filling up space

Tags: css, joomla

I'm using a joomla theme (yoo_downtown) on this site - www.bhct.bm and once you set it to two columns, it's supposed to fill up remaining white space. This was in face working earlier, but now it's stopped doing it for some reason. Can anyone take a look and see what the problem is?

Comment: I'm looking, but see nothing but this question.

Comment: You can't see the question? Or you can't open the page?

Comment: www.bhct.bm cant be opened. Please use @ so ican get your messgaes in my mailbox.

Comment: Ok got it opened. Now which column are your reffering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have:

```
#maininner{width:490px}
```

in your style declaration, which is overriding your earlier:

```
#maininner{width:735px}
```

What's causing *that*, I'm unsure, but there's obviously something wrong going on, because you have 5 separate declarations for #maininner's width in your inline style. Are you calling some function multiple times?

(BTW, the fact that your entire page is stretched over 8 very long lines of markup isn't making debugging very easy)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that yesterday too - Joomla cache was on and was kind of botching things up a bit